# How to parse a JSON object where name is 0

Tags: jquery, json

I'm new to jQuery Ajax. I'm sending a request and receiving a response of the below format.

```
{"status":{"0":"User name already registered"}}
```

How can I parse this JSON object with name as 0 and display the value **"User name already registered"**.

Comment: @W.K.S  JSON.Parse is not a function - This is what I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the JSON using JSON.parse()
and then access the message using status["0"];

```
var json = "{\"status\":{\"0\":\"User name already registered\"}}";
alert(JSON.parse(json).status["0"]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJts2/).

Comment: How to get the name say how to parse for 0

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean?

Comment: I'm asking in a JSON object, how to get both name and value

Answer (score 1):

```
var data= {"status":{"0":"User name already registered"}}
```

To access the value of status

```
var value = data.status
```

returns {"0":"User name already registered"}

To access the value of 0

```
value = data.status[0]
```

returns {"User name already registered"}

Or if you have multiple values

```
$.each(data.status, function (key, val) {
    console.log(key + ' = ' + val);
 });
```

will print "0 = User name already registered"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you store it in a `response` variable:

```
var response = {"status":{"0":"User name already registered"}};
```

You can access it with

```
 response.status["0"]; // This will be the "User name already registered" message
```

This is already a JSON object. If you are receiving it as a string, simply wrap it in a `JSON.parse(myString)`.

Comment: How can get name as well from the JSON object